# Windows: Disable / Enable USB Hub WITHOUT reboot

Tags: windows, usb, wdk

I would like to be able to programmatically disable or enable a USB hub in order to make the USB devices connected to it unavailable or available, respectively. I did some testing using device manager and then using ***Devcon***, and found that when certain devices are connected to the hub (specifically some Android phones), it cannot be disabled right away, and it is marked for disabling after reboot instead. 
I tried to get over this problem by trying to also disable problematic devices connected to the hub, but this also failed.
I also tried using the ***SetupDixxx*** API directly, and even some USB IOCTLs, but I did not manage to get this task done.
I believe there ought to be a way of forcing immediate disable of a hub without reboot. I would appreciate it if anyone could point me to the right way.

Thanks in advance,
Ziv